# Binding listbox to a SQL database image field

Tags: c#, sql, image, xaml, listbox

I want to display image from a image field on SQL database using C# and WPF. I've tried the following codes, but it just retrieve all fields other than the image field data.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="552" Margin="10,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="754" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontWeight="Bold"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="150" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding PhotoID}"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Left"

                         Margin="5,0,10,0" Width="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and in C# section I'm using the following codes as well:

```
Private void RetrieveData()
    {
        string ConString = conn;
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

        }

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            CmdString = "Select ID,Name,PhotoID from Employees";
            RetrieveData();
            listBox.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;


        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("db error");
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually, there is no problem with the above mentioned codes. I just changed the field data type from image to binary in SQL database and this way problem solved.

I don't know why is that, but seems there's a problem with image data type.